# How to overcome eBay CSS limits for auctions' pages?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, ebay

On eBay you can code the content of a `<div>` on the auction's page. The problem is that you can't edit the `<head>` content.

I tried using inside the `<div>` something like this:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
      my styles...
</style>
```

It works on Chrome and Firefox but it doesn't work on Internet Explorer.
Do you have any hint other than manually write all the `style="..."` attribute in each element? *

I'm not looking for W3C validation, eBay pages are already broken. I just need it to work cross browser.

---

* Unless there is some automatic way to do it.

PS: I don't have enough reputation to create the eBay tag yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a tool to convert your external style to inline stylesheets, such as used for email-marketing and other areas where inlinestyling is the only option

- http://inlinestyler.torchboxapps.com/styler/

Answer (score 1):

Browsers shouldn't honour <link rel="stylesheet"> outside of the header, but many do. Please check the terms and conditions as I'm sure eBay would try to stop this (you could override their page styles for instance). Alternatives may include an iframe back to your site (unless that is forbidden too).